# Excel macro vlookup R1C1 perfomance issue

Tags: excel, vba, performance, vlookup

I am working on a macro in which I have to compare two string values. 
I have used vlookup to manage this and though I can see it takes up a lot of resources it has been working quite well. Until this week. 
The resources go to full and Excel freezes. If I cancel the action with esc it occasionally gives the error 1004 autofill method of range class failed. Other times it seems the action is finished, I see the result of the compare and it accepts the hard stop. I use the following code.

```
Sub combineMessageDataCLFArchi()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Worksheets("clf_import").Range("F1").FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-4],archi_relations!C[-5]:C[-1],3,FALSE),0)"
Range("F1").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("F:F")

Worksheets("clf_import").Range("G1").FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-5],archi_relations!C[-6]:C[-2],5,FALSE),0)"
Range("G1").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("G:G")

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

There were no changes made to the code prior to me looking for a solution. 
I have tried to just run one of the lookups but that gives the same result. 
I have tried to return a TRUE but had the same result.
I have tried to do the double vlookup perfomance hack but did not manage to make it work. 
If the error is thrown it is thrown on Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("G:G")

Comment: I've tried your code `Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("G:G")`, and it made Excell app suffer a lot, but it still survive to fill the formula from G1 to G1048576 after 1 minute pass... and then I experience "lag" when I continue to use the computer. So probably it because the computer is not powerful enough to have the formula in the whole column. Is it possible for you to limit the filling of the formula ? maybe put a limit for the formula filling based on the last row with value in another column ?

Comment: Thanks, I have tried to limit the range but it keeps crashing. Am now looking for a different solution outside excel.

Comment: So you have tried changing the code from `Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("F:F")` to something like `Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("F1:F50")` and from `Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("G:G")` to something like `Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("G1:G50")` and it still keep crashing?

Comment: Within the environment is has to run in yes. And they will not add power just to compute this excel sheet. Thanks for the suggestions.